# Change background color of div when checkbox is clicked

Tags: jquery, css, forms, checkbox

I have a form with several checkboxes, like this:

```
<div><input type='checkbox' name='groupid' value='1'>1</div>
<div><input type='checkbox' name='groupid' value='2'>2</div>
<div><input type='checkbox' name='groupid' value='3'>3</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is when the checkbox is checked, change the background color of the div, and when it's unchecked, remove the background color.  How can I do this using jquery?

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

jQuery:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $(this).parent().addClass("redBackground"); 
    }else{
        $(this).parent().removeClass("redBackground");  
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.redBackground{
    background-color: red;  
}
```

I'd recommend using Add/Remove class, as opposed to changing the CSS of the parent `div` directly.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/uJcB7/

Comment: What if I have to target a specific form? This page has dynamic data, and I have other form with checkboxes and so I don't need the effect on every form in the page, just one.

Comment: change your initial selector. `$("#formID input[type='checkbox']")`

Answer (score 5):

One solution with direct CSS attribute changing:

```
$(":checkbox").on("change", function() {
    var that = this;
    $(this).parent().css("background-color", function() {
        return that.checked ? "#ff0000" : "";
    });
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/YQD7c/

---

Another solution using `toggleClass`:

```
$(":checkbox").on("change", function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("checked", this.checked);
});​
```

Where you define class `checked` in CSS as follows:

```
.checked {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/YQD7c/1/

Comment: What if I have to target a specific form? This page has dynamic data, and I have other form with checkboxes and so I don't need the effect on every form in the page, just one.

Comment: @DobotJr: Add the concrete form to the selector, like `$("#myform :checkbox")`.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that this is an old thread, but I came searching and this answer got me most of the way. (needed some tweaking for WordPress) So if someone else lands on this same page that is using WordPress, give this a shot, worked great for me.

The Script

```
jQuery("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
if(jQuery(this).is(":checked")){
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass("greenBackground"); 
}
else{
    jQuery(this).parent().removeClass("greenBackground");  
} });
```

The CSS

```
.greenBackground{
background-color: #06530e;  
color: #ffffff;}
```